# Returning #VALUE! for loop designed to compare values in a comma separated list?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm comparing a comma separated list to see if any of the values match a single value. I believe the problem is occurring with this line of code:

```
If INDEXLIST(damageListCell, ",", n) = CStr(Range(damageTypeCell).Value) Then
```

`INDEXLIST` is a function that returns the a string a string that is the end from the beginning of a comma separated list.This list is at the location of `damageListCell` which is a string that references a box in Excel.

`damageTypeCell` is an argument that is being passed into this function as a string and is the idea of a box in Excel "D5" for example.

I do not think that `CStr(Range(damageTypeCell).Value)` is returning a string of the data and the relevant cell and therefore the expression just doesn't work.

I've tried all the ways I can think of to pass that sell and as a string this includes:
`CStr(Range(damageTypeCell).Value)`
`Range(damageTypeCell)`
`Range(damageTypeCell).Value`

```
For i = 1 To list_langth
    n = n + 1
    If INDEXLIST(damageListCell, ",", n) = CStr(Range(damageTypeCell).Value) Then
    Damage_Fill = 1
        Exit For
    Else
        Damage_Fill = 0
    End If
Next i

End Function
```

---

```
Function INDEXLIST(strList As String, strSeparator As String, lngIndex As 
Long) As String
'Syntax
'=INDEXLIST(List,Separator,Index)

Dim ListArray() As String

ListArray() = Split(strList, strSeparator)

INDEXLIST = ListArray(lngIndex - 1)

    End Function
```

---

```
Public Function CountChrInString(Expression As String, Character As String) As Long
'
' ? CountChrInString("a/b/c", "/")
'  2
' ? CountChrInString("a/b/c", "\")
'  0
' ? CountChrInString("//////", "/")
'  6
' ? CountChrInString(" a / b / c ", "/")
'  2
' ? CountChrInString("a/b/c", " / ")
'  0
'
    Dim iResult As Long
    Dim sParts() As String

    sParts = Split(Expression, Character)

    iResult = UBound(sParts, 1)

    If (iResult = -1) Then
    iResult = 0
    End If

    CountChrInString = iResult

End Function
```

Excel is returning #VALUE! When this function is ran however it should return a 1 or a 0.

Comment: When trying to debug a UDF it's best to call it from a VBA Sub, not from the worksheet.

Comment: Can you confirm list_langth is the correct variable?

Answer (score 0):

In the function `INDEXLIST`, change

`ListArray() = Split(strList, strSeparator)`

to

`ListArray() = Split(Range(strList), strSeparator)`

Answer (score 0):

`lngIndex As Long` changed to `lngIndex As Integer` in the Function INDEXLIST.

`If INDEXLIST(damageListCell, ",", n) = CStr(Range(damageTypeCell).Value) Then` changed to `If INDEXLIST(damageListCell, ",", i) = INDEXLIST(damageTypeCell, ",", 1) Then` and remove the n variable entirely